App should navigate to home even if internet is off
Currently, I am checking on SplashScreen whether token exist or not, on that basis app navigates to either SignIn or Home.
On Home when I turn off the internet, it shows a dialog that there is no internet connection. By turning it on, the dialog disappears.
The problem is when I close the app and turn off the internet and then open the app it navigates to SignIn. I expect it to be navigated to Home as token is already there.
It works normally when I turn on the internet and visit the app, it navigates to Home directly.
Need an idea to resolve this issue.
Here's the SplashScreen code for navigating the app.
 Future<void> navigate() async {
    final bearer = await ref.read(bearerTokenProvider.future); // stored in local db

    if (!mounted) return;

    GoRouter.of(context)
        .pushReplacement(bearer != null ? RoutePaths.home : RoutePaths.login);
  }


your using firebase_auth for user sign in process?

@ChamalkaGunawardana no, using rest api

what is your database to store the users

I'd suggest sharing some of the code of the logic of navigating to the home screen, or the sign in... Maybe doing some debugging there might help as well!

@ChamalkaGunawardana mysql

uhm mysql is not running on your phone, so how can you store a token there?

@Thomas I am not storing the token on the server, it is being stored in local db i.e. hive. see the code I have added the comment.

@Thomas I answered the firebase_auth question. he asked if im using that. see, while i login to the app i also store the token in my hive so next time when user opens the app he redirects to the home page. this is perfectly working. the issue arises when I turn off the internet and then open the app. it doesnot go to home and navigates to sign in.

since a moment before you hadn't mentioned hive but only MySQL, that's why there was confusion.
You are using provider? do you do anything different when there is no network connection where you actually read the token from hive?

would make sense to add the code for bearerTokenProvider

@Thomas it's simply fetching the token, final bearer = await _persistenceHelper.getString(_authKey);

im using riverpod. and im using navigate() method mentioned in the question in initState of the splash. splash is the first screen of my app

please add the full code of bearerTokenProvider to the question also what does _persistenceHelper do? is there any output in your debug window when this happens. It feels pretty strange

@Aiman I bet the bearerTokenProvider code is the problem. Either:

you are not storing the bearer token to the local db the right way
or bearerTokenProvider is not fetching that data correctly

Please provide the code where you do both

its working fine when internet is on. it redirects to the home screen if it is already logged in.

You should paste the code of bearerTokenProvider so that we can get more info about your logic.
If it does not work when the internet is off then your cashing logic is probably faulty. Paste the code where you handle token caching

Did you cache your token when it is validated? If yes then you can just check your cached token while navigating from MaterialApp.
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String? token;


  @override
  void initState() {
    token = fetchFromCache();
    
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
          ...
          initialRoute: token!=null? "/home": "/splash",
          //or if using home:
          //home: token!=null? HomePage(): SplashPage(),
        );
  }
}


recheck my question, I have added the code.

To ensure that the app navigates to the Home screen when the token exists, regardless of the internet connection status, you can modify the SplashScreen code to check for the presence of the token and navigate accordingly. you can use shared_preferences for this. SharedPreferences allows you to persist key-value pairs locally on the device.
First, make the userSignIn function so that after a user signIn, the token is stored in the cache. I don't know what your code is like, make it as you want.
 Future<String?> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    // Assume here you have some logic to authenticate the user and retrieve the bearer token
    String? token = await _authenticateUser(email, password);

    // Save the token to SharedPreferences if sign-in is successful
    if (token != null) {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setString('bearerToken', token);
    }

    return token;
  }

create the singUp function in the same and null the token when user signOut
 Future<void> signOut() async {
    // Remove the token from SharedPreferences
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.remove('bearerToken');
  }

to navigate pages, make it like this:
Future<void> navigate(BuildContext context) async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  
  // Retrieve the bearer token from SharedPreferences
  String? bearer = prefs.getString('bearerToken');

  // Check if the widget is still mounted to avoid setState on disposed widget
  if (!mounted) return;

  // Navigate based on the presence of the bearer token
  Navigator.pushReplacement(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => bearer != null ? HomeScreen() : LoginScreen(),
    ),
  );
}


He writes that he already stores the token, so that does not seem to be the problem

@Thomas No  he only  stores  the token in the database. There is no way to fetch token when the internet connection is lost. to do that, you have to store the token in the app's cash memory.

I am already storing the token in hive

Ah, that was the information that was missing

@Aiman you are already storing the token in your database but you are not store it in app cash memory

@ChamalkaGunawardana how do you come to that comclusion?

@ChamalkaGunawardana Aiman clarified that he stores it in hive, I don't see why you can dispute that then
